# How can I add an anchor tag to my URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, tags, anchor, addition

MVC 3.net I want to add an anchor to the end a url.

I tried to include an anchor query string but the hash '#' changes to %23 or something like that in the url.

Is there a way of working around this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690466/redirect-to-a-hash-from-the-controller-using-redirecttoaction

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is an overload of the [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx) helper that allows you to specify the fragment:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Link Text",           // linkText
    "Action",              // actionName
    "Controller",          // controllerName
    null,                  // protocol
    null,                  // hostName
    "fragment",            // fragment
    new { id = "123" },    // routeValues
    null                   // htmlAttributes
)
```

will produce (assuming default routes):

```
<a href="/Controller/Action/123#fragment">Link Text</a>
```

---

UPDATE:

and if you wanted to do this within a controller action performing a redirect you could use the [GenerateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703653.aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        null,
        "Action",
        "Controller",
        null,
        null,
        "fragment",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = "123" }),
        Url.RouteCollection,
        Url.RequestContext,
        false
    );
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: thanks darin. in this case i am using redirect to action to generate a url from a controller, and it only has 6 overloads not including fragment. any solution to this?

Comment: In this case you could use the [UrlHelper.GenerateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703653.aspx) method within your controller which allows you to specify a fragment and then redirect to the resulting url. I have updated my post to provide an example.

Comment: Plz see this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690466/redirect-to-a-hash-from-the-controller-using-redirecttoaction