# MVC 3 Appending Anchor to outgoing URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes, anchor

I am implementing a non-Javascript page for a client. The page contains a number of third party grids. When JS is turned off and a sort is performed the page i,s posted back to the server , which is fine. However, I want the page to navigate  to the grid that was sorted.

I can do this by using anchors, and I have tested it. However, as I am new to MVC I don't know how to append the anchor to the outgoing URL.

For example I may get a URL like `Team/User/42?SortGrid1-field-asc`

After it has been processed by the controller I need the URL to be sent to the client as 
`Team/User/42?SortGrid1-field-asc#Grid1`

Any ideas?

I have tried to append the anchor internally using lines like

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("User", "Team", new { Id = Id }) + "#Grid1");
```

But fail to see how to stop it going off in an infinite loop. If I redirect to another action then I go down a whole new path , which, code wise, will go on forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the answer to a question I posted: [How can I add an anchor tag to my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904835/how-can-i-add-an-anchor-tag-to-my-url)

I think you may have to go through the controller and use generateURL to get the anchor into the url

Comment: I tried adding a line like:   if (Session["IsJavaScriptEnabled"] == null || !(bool) Session["IsJavaScriptEnabled"])  {
                return Redirect(Url.Action("UserNonJs", "Team", new { Id = Id }) + "#PanelBar-2"); to the User Action Method, But it only works once because next time I come in through the nonJS Route.  
            } How do I redirect back to the same action method without causing an infinite loop?