# Redirect to a hash from the controller using "RedirectToAction"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I want to return an anchor from Mvc Controller

Controller name=  DefaultController;

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
{
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "region")
}
```

So that the url when directed to index is

```
http://localhost/Default/#region
```

So that

```
<a href=#region>the content should be focus here</a>
```

I am not asking if you can do it like this: [How can I add an anchor tag to my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904835/how-can-i-add-an-anchor-tag-to-my-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904835/how-can-i-add-an-anchor-tag-to-my-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC RedirectToAction with anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602788/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-anchor)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I found this way:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
{
    return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#region");
}
```

You can also use this verbose way:

```
var url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
    null,
    "Index",
    "DefaultController",
    null,
    null,
    "region",
    null,
    null,
    Url.RequestContext,
    false
);
return Redirect(url);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703653.aspx

Comment: You are a genious mate! Here what I ended doing:            return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index",new{  PKMvrEmployeeId = MvrId }) + "#region");

Comment: +1 for using RedirectResult instead of calling Redirect(..) method. 
In MVC under release and IIS6 you can end up with exceptions caused by redirecting because a request is perhaps already redirected, or part of a child action, or content is already sent.

Comment: In MVC 5, when using RedirectToAction it appears to escape the # to a %23. Is no one else experiencing this?

Comment: For me, it's going back up again when I use the same method.

Answer (score 16):

Great answer gdoron. Here's another way that I use (just to add to the available solutions here).

```
return Redirect(String.Format("{0}#{1}", Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" }), "anchor_hash");
```

Obviously, with gdoron's answer this could be made a cleaner with the following in this simple case;

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#anchor_hash");
```

Comment: The first option works well if your action is in a different controller.

Answer (score 14):

A simple way in dot net core

```
public IActionResult MyAction(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "default", "region");
}
```

The above yields **/default/index#region**. The 3rd parameter is **fragment** which it adds after a #.

[Microsoft docs - ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_String_System_String_)

Answer (score 5):

To Expand on Squall's answer: Using string interpolation makes for cleaner code. It also works for actions on different controllers.

```
return Redirect($"{Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" })}#anchor");
```