# How to pass #text with URL when redirecting from RedirectToAction after post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to pass #text with URL when redirecting from `RedirectToAction` after post method

My URL: `www.test.com/testController/testAction/15`

I want this URL to be

```
www.test.com/testController/testAction/15#test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to a hash from the controller using "RedirectToAction"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690466/redirect-to-a-hash-from-the-controller-using-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Redirect` for this in MVC

```
return Redirect("~/testController/testAction?id=15#test");
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this RedirectResult

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("testAction", "testController", new { id = 15 }) +"#Text");
```