# Is there simple way to use bookmarks in controller action's generated urls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently I am working with simple Forum module in ASP.NET MVC 3 which i will add later to my main application. The possibility to link to certain blocks like div used to present thread replies is very useful.

I figured out something which work and propably will be enough for my needs, I just wonder if there is something more elegant and simple aswell. I found a solution using ActionFilters, and since I'm quite begginner in MVC I would like to find some easier solution (if exists). Well i will propably learn ActionFilters soon aswell :)

So here is what I've done:

```
public ActionResult ShowThread(int id, int? postID)
{

    var thread = db.ForumThreads.Find(id);
    if (postID != null)
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Action("ShowThread",new {id=id})+"#post-"+postID.ToString());
    }
    return View(thread);
}
```

I know it is quite simple, but it is working. Also it doesn't check if the postID is valid yet, but it is not a part of question.

Comment: See this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904835/how-can-i-add-an-anchor-tag-to-my-url

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for bookmarks in searchbox, didn't think about looking for anchor...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use one of RedirectToAction overloads: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470154(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470154%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). 
Perhaps, in your case, the next one would do: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
And the call would be:

```
    return this.RedirectToAction("ShowThread", new { id = id, post = postID });
```

Another (simpler, but not safer!) solution is to format the URL you need to redirect to and to use the Redirect() method like this:

```
    var redirectUrl = string.Format("/Home/ShowThread/{0}?post={1}", id, postID);
    return this.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Pay attention to your URL mappings, though. The examples above assume the method

```
    public ActionResult ShowThread(int id, int? post)
```

is in HomeController and the default route has not been changed. Otherwise you should

1. adjust the URL prepending the controller name (w/o Controller), or
2. change your default route to map to the controller's name.