# In MVC4, how to redirect to a view from a controller action with parameters in the Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view

In my MVC4 login view, I have several sections defined:

- login - /User/Login#login or - /User/Login
- register - /User/Login#register
- lostpassword - - /User/Login#lostpassword

The JS on the page picks up the right form area to present.

Everything works fine for login - validation, etc.  However if the registration fails, how do I return to the view with the added `#register` parameter?

-- Update --
I forgot to mention that this is from a controller and all validation errors need to be passed back to it.  So, `return Redirect("...")` doesn't work

Comment: This should help: [How can I add an anchor tag to my URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904835/how-can-i-add-an-anchor-tag-to-my-url)

Comment: @Shad - Thanks but see my update.  Need to do this from a controller action.

Comment: Why not make it as a parameter ie. /User/Login/Register then map the route in your RouteRegistrar

Comment: @Raymund - while that's a good idea, the route is `url: "User/Login#registerform"` , but the hashtag gets URL encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The following does the trick

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "User") + "#registerform");
```

URL is `~/Login/User#registerform`.

Answer (score 0):

This way will work:

```
return RedirectToAction("NewAction", new { 
     id = model.Id, 
     registerParam = model.registerId
});
```

PS: If New Action fails you can do the same thing back to the current action method, with some error parameter.